# Android textview rotate with background

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create a layout something similar to below picture. My problem is how can I rotate text view and add a background to it. Tried custom textview with draw rotated. But cant position correctly with that method

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/dealItemPerc"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:background="@drawable/deal_percentage_back"
            android:rotation="-45"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/app_black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Tried with a button but that also not worked because cant position correctly.

[image]

Comment: what do want exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Created like this. rotated frame layout with text view inside of it. Don't know why the heck someone gave minus rate.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <me.dushyantha.mywebserviceapp.SquareImageView
            android:id="@+id/dealItemImage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/detail_rounded_block" >
        </me.dushyantha.mywebserviceapp.SquareImageView>

        <FrameLayout 
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
            android:rotation="-45" 
            >
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/dealItemPerc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:background="@drawable/deal_percentage_back"
                />
        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: See Screenshot]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.test1.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:rotation="-45"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Nothing** to **do** with **java** code

Build and run the project.

**Done**